# stock quotes for android

Tags: android, stockquotes, yahoo-finance

Is there a way to download and parse stock quotes from yahoo or google using the android platform?

Thanks

Comment: I see you have added a bounty for this question.  I was wondering what further information you are looking for that is not in the existing answers?

Comment: Did u find a way for this? if so can u tell me the code in android for achieving this?

Comment: http://rtfacm.posterous.com/yahoo-finance-parsing-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Android includes an http client and Xml + Json libraries.

Comment: do you know where I can read about these?

Comment: Details are available on android developer site.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with straight HTTP using [YQL](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20google.igoogle.stock%20where%20stock%3D%27YHOO%27%3B&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=)

[YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console) is useful for testing.  The example above uses the google.igoogle.stock table

Comment: how exactly are you retrieving this data?

Comment: exactly through http get, that's how yql works.  How is it indexed into the YQL table?  Not sure

Answer (score 1):

Redistribution of Yahoo Finance data is only allowed if you are using the badges the team has created: http://finance.yahoo.com/badges. Using YQL for non-personal use would be a breach of terms of service.

[Google Finance APIs and Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/) ([Terms](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/api-terms.html))

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog post could help you:

http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2009/01/truly-simple-stock-api.html

It uses Yahoo Finance to retrieve stock quotes.

This uses the same service, but does it download into a spreadsheet

http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

However it could be useful since there is a lot of explanaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the BuzzBox SDK for android and in particular to the example here:

http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/quickstart

The example is using the Yahoo weather api to build a notification weather app. If you simply adapt it to get stock data using YQL as suggesed before [YQL](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20google.igoogle.stock%20where%20stock=%27YHOO%27;&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=)

It's a very similar JSON parsing problem.